# HeatMap con Python mostrando 2 valores en cada celda

Tags: python-3.9, seaborn

Estoy tratando de hacer un HeatMap para mostrar el número de eventos de cada código (count) de mi dataframe:
Mi cuestión es cómo puedo transformar mi dataframe

```
cl  code        count
1   E04F  15/02     9785
2   E01D  21/00     7309
3   E04F  15/02038  5584
4   E04F  15/04     5024
1   E04B   1/80     4641
2   E04F  15/107    4420
3   E04F2201/0153   4112
4   E04H   9/021    4053
1   E01D  22/00     3520
2   E04B   1/86     3327
3   E04F  15/105    3266
4   E04B   1/2403   3111
1   E01C  13/08     3064
2   E04G  23/0218   3019
3   E04H   1/1205   2979
4   E04F2201/0115   2952
1   E04F  15/10     2893
2   E04B   1/24     2858
3   E04H   6/42     2821
4   E04F  13/08     2747
```

Quisiera transformar este dataframe en algo como esto donde el número es df[‘count’] y abajo dentro de cada celda aparezca el df[‘code’].
He tratado de pivotar la tabla (sin éxito) utilizando la columna cl para que quedara de esta manera:

```
9785    4641    3520    3064    2893
7309    4420    3327    3019    2858
5584    4112    3266    2979    2821
5024    4053    3111    2952    2747
```

4 filas por columna y asociado al número (count) estaría el code.
Pero no sé cómo hacerlo porque si lo hago por cl, tengo esto:

```
code    E01C 13/08  E01D 21/00  E01D 22/00  E04B 1/24   E04B 1/2403 E04B 1/80   E04B 1/86   E04F 13/08  E04F 15/02  E04F 15/02038   E04F 15/04  E04F 15/10  E04F 15/105 E04F 15/107 E04F2201/0115   E04F2201/0153   E04G 23/0218    E04H 1/1205 E04H 6/42   E04H 9/021
cl                                                                              
1   3064.0  NaN 3520.0  NaN NaN 4641.0  NaN NaN 9785.0  NaN NaN 2893.0  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   NaN 7309.0  NaN 2858.0  NaN NaN 3327.0  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 4420.0  NaN NaN 3019.0  NaN NaN NaN
3   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 5584.0  NaN NaN 3266.0  NaN NaN 4112.0  NaN 2979.0  2821.0  NaN
4   NaN NaN NaN NaN 3111.0  NaN NaN 2747.0  NaN NaN 5024.0  NaN NaN NaN 2952.0  NaN NaN NaN NaN 4053.0
```

La idea es conseguir algo como esto donde cada celdita tiene el count y el code.

[image: HeatMap]

Alguna idea de por dónde seguir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que lo más simple es separar en dos datframes diferentes los contadores (que se usarán para elegir los colores en el heatmap) y los textos que deben aparecer en cada celda (que serán una cadena que contenga el valor del contador y el de su correspondiente código).

A seaborn le puedes pedir que cree el heatmap a partir de un dataframe, pero que tome los textos a poner en las celdas de otro.

Este es el código que implementa mi enfoque:

```
# Este es el dataframe de partida, el tuyo
print(df)
------
    cl            code  count
0    1      E04F 15/02   9785
1    2      E01D 21/00   7309
2    3   E04F 15/02038   5584
3    4      E04F 15/04   5024
4    1       E04B 1/80   4641
5    2     E04F 15/107   4420
6    3  E04F 2201/0153   4112
7    4      E04H 9/021   4053
8    1      E01D 22/00   3520
9    2       E04B 1/86   3327
10   3     E04F 15/105   3266
11   4     E04B 1/2403   3111
12   1      E01C 13/08   3064
13   2    E04G 23/0218   3019
14   3     E04H 1/1205   2979
15   4  E04F 2201/0115   2952
16   1      E04F 15/10   2893
17   2       E04B 1/24   2858
18   3       E04H 6/42   2821
19   4      E04F 13/08   2747
```

Ahora lo procesamos para crear con él un par de diccionarios cuyas claves serán los valores de `cl` y cuyos valores serán listas de números en el primero (los valores de `count`) y listas de cadenas en el segundo (los que queremos mostrar en cada celda):

```
values = defaultdict(list)
texts = defaultdict(list)
for i, fila in df.iterrows():
  values[fila["cl"]].append(int(fila['count']))
  texts[fila["cl"]].append(f"{fila['count']}\n{fila['code']}")
```

Tras este procesamiento hemos creado estos dos diccionarios:

```
values = {1: [9785, 4641, 3520, 3064, 2893],
          2: [7309, 4420, 3327, 3019, 2858],
          3: [5584, 4112, 3266, 2979, 2821],
          4: [5024, 4053, 3111, 2952, 2747]}
texts =  {1: ['9785\nE04F 15/02', '4641\nE04B 1/80', '3520\nE01D 22/00', '3064\nE01C 13/08', '2893\nE04F 15/10'],
          2: ['7309\nE01D 21/00', '4420\nE04F 15/107', '3327\nE04B 1/86', '3019\nE04G 23/0218', '2858\nE04B 1/24'],
          3: ['5584\nE04F 15/02038', '4112\nE04F 2201/0153', '3266\nE04F 15/105', '2979\nE04H 1/1205', '2821\nE04H 6/42'],
          4: ['5024\nE04F 15/04', '4053\nE04H 9/021', '3111\nE04B 1/2403', '2952\nE04F 2201/0115', '2747\nE04F 13/08']})
```

Estos diccionarios pueden convertirse fácilmente en dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(values, orient="index")
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(texts, orient="index")
```

por ejemplo el dataframe `df1` se vería así:

```
      0     1     2     3     4
1  9785  4641  3520  3064  2893
2  7309  4420  3327  3019  2858
3  5584  4112  3266  2979  2821
4  5024  4053  3111  2952  2747
```

El `df2` no lo muestro porque no se ve muy bonito, debido a los `\n` que tiene en cada celda y que pandas no interpreta como salto de línea (aunque como veremos seaborn sí lo hará)

Finalmente podemos crear ya el heatmap usando estos dos dataframes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.heatmap(df1, annot=df2, fmt="", ax=ax, xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False)
fig.set_size_inches(16, 4)
```

[image: Resultado]

## Bonus

Si tienes instalado latex en tu sistema tienes mucha flexibilidad para formatear como desees los contenidos de cada celda. Por ejemplo, en el siguiente código hago que las cadenas de texto contenidas en cada celda sean instrucciones latex para poner el valor numérico en grande y en negrita encima del codigo más pequeño:

```
for i, fila in df.iterrows():
  values[fila["cl"]].append(int(fila['count']))
  txt = r"\begin{tabular}{c}\LARGE{\textbf{%s}}\\\large{%s}\end{tabular}" % (fila["count"], fila["code"])
  texts[fila["cl"]].append(txt)
```

El código anterior forma parte de la creación del diccionario `texts`, el resto de código para crear `df1` y `df2` sería idéntico.

Para hacer que seaborn (a través de matplotlib) use LaTeX para renderizar ese texto debes hacer (aprovecho para mostrar otro cmap que creo que queda mejor):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.rcParams['text.usetex'] = True
mpl.rcParams['text.latex.preamble'] = [r'\usepackage{amsmath}']


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
sns.heatmap(df1, annot=df2, fmt="", ax=ax, xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False,  cmap="vlag")
fig.set_size_inches(12, 4)
```

El resultado es ahora:

[image: Resultado usando latex]

Una paleta más similar a la que usas en la figura de tu pregunta sería `cmap="YlOrBr"`, que quedaría así:

[image: Otra paleta]

Para que lo anterior funcione tienes que tener instalado latex. En Google Colab por defecto no lo está, pero puedes añadirlo ejecutando antes una celda con:

```
! apt install texlive-latex-recommended 
! apt install texlive-latex-extra
! apt install texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-fonts-extra cm-super dvipng
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, es justo lo que necesitaba!!! No tenía instalado latex y la verdad es que es muy versátil, estoy trasteando ahora un poco.

Comment: @rcmoreira De nada. Si al intentar replicar mi solución encuentras algún problema no dudes en preguntar de nuevo. Si todo te funciona puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada para dar por cerrado el tema.